# Trouble installing sklearn in command prompt in python, getting ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, command-prompt

I am trying to install sklearn in my command prompt but I keep getting the same error.

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\paula\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\paula\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\paula\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0nihy7su\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1'
       cwd: None
```

I have tried `pip install sklearn`, `pip install -U sklearn` and the same with `scikit learn` instead and they all gave the same error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
I am using Python 3.9.1 on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.9.1 is a bleeding edge version as of now *-Dec 2020-* and you should be aware that some libraries might not support it. Further information can be found in the following github issue:

[Failed To Install scikit-learn with Python 3.9 on Windows](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18621)

You can try installing it with the command,

`pip install --pre -U scikit-learn`

Comment: Thanks BcK i managed to install it with your help. However for anyone referring to this page with a similar error try it with sklearn as well as scikit learn one or the other should work.

Comment: Great, can you please mark the question as solved ?

Comment: sorry i just joined to ask this question how do i do that

Comment: nevermind i figured it out thanks again for the help